# Rethink as a noun

Tags: nouns, word-usage

I came across the word 'rethink' so many times. But it still puzzles me if it is correct to use the word 'rethink' as a noun. Is it okay to use the word 'rethink' as a noun?

Your inputs are highly appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Please look up in a dictionary.

Comment: All verbs can be nouned. Some are more cromulent than others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Rethink:**

noun: a reassessment of something, especially one that results in changes being made:
(a last-minute rethink of their tactics)

[rethink](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/rethink?q=rethink)

Rethink can be used as a noun, **afterthought. second thought or reconsideration** can be an alternatives.

Comment: Try to provide a link to the source. This is GR.